# CFWheels - Calculated property generates column error in query

Tags: sql, coldfusion, railo, cfwheels

Ok, so this is really confusing me now, because I had this working a while back and something has changed which has caused my calculated properties to not work.

I have a "page" controller that does a findAll() on the "link" model. This works great, except for when I try to include a calculated property (which used to work).

**page.cfc (controller)**

```
<cfset linkListHottest = model("link").findAll(

            select="

                links.linkID,
                linkTitle,
                linkPoints,
                linkAuthority,
                linkCreated,
<!--- Here I specifiy the 'property' names from the model --->
                linkUpVoteCount,
                linkDownVoteCount,
                linkCommentCount,

                users.userID,
                userName,

                categories.categoryID,
                categoryTitle,
                categoryToken",

            include="user,category", 
            order="linkPoints DESC",
            handle="linkListHottestPaging",

            page=params.page,
            perPage=5

        ) />
```

**link.cfc (model)**

```
<cffunction name="init">

        <cfset table("links") />

<!--- These three lines aren't populating my queries on the link model --->
        <cfset property(name="linkUpVoteCount", sql="(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE votes.linkID = links.linkID AND voteType = 1)") />
        <cfset property(name="linkDownVoteCount", sql="(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE votes.linkID = links.linkID AND voteType = 0)") />
        <cfset property(name="linkCommentCount", sql="(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE comments.linkID = links.linkID AND commentRemoved = 0)") />

        <cfset belongsTo(name="user", modelName="user", joinType="outer", foreignKey="userID") />
        <cfset belongsTo(name="category", modelName="category", joinType="outer", foreignKey="categoryID") />

        <cfset hasMany(name="vote", modelName="vote", joinType="outer", foreignKey="linkID") />
        <cfset hasMany(name="comment", modelName="comment", joinType="outer", foreignKey="linkID") />   

        <cfset validatesPresenceOf(property='linkTitle') />
        <cfset validatesPresenceOf(property='linkURL') />
        <cfset validate(property='linkURL', method='isValidURL') />
        <cfset validate(property='linkURL', method="validateUniqueUrl", when="onCreate") />

    </cffunction>
```

**home.cfm (view)**

```
#linkListHottest.linkUpVoteCount#
```

I get the following error:

> Unknown column 'linkUpVoteCount' in 'field list'

Ok, I thought, let's remove the column names from the SELECT in the findAll() and see if that solves it. Nope:

> column [LINKUPVOTECOUNT] not found in query, columns are
>   [linkID,linkTitle,linkPoints,linkAuthority,linkCreated,userID,userName,categoryID,categoryTitle,categoryToken]

So it seems like a catch 22 situation. It's almost as if my "link" model is ignoring the properties set there entirely.

I would appreciate any feedback on where I'm going wrong (I'm sure it's me!).

Many thanks,
Michael.

Comment: If you remove only linkUpVoteCount, does the same error occur for the column linkDownVoteCount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like this is a bug with Wheels. I suggest filing an issue.

Comment: Hi Chris, yes, I placed an 'issue' on the GitHub for CFWheels...is that the correct area? So in summary, I think calculated properties when used with SELECT clauses in findAll() functions are borked. By borked I mean...broken :)

Comment: 50 points for you Chris for confirming the bug and also the fact that despite it; wheels is awesome and I appreciate all your work and efforts on it. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo, good job. Which version of CFWheels was this?

Comment: @HenriqueOrdine it is CFWheels 1.1.8 (the latest version as of this writing).

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with your framework, but try this:

```
<cfset property(name="linkUpVoteCount", sql="(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE votes.linkID = links.linkID AND voteType = 1) as linkUpVoteCount") />
```

Puts the `as linkUpVoteCount` alias outside the sql subquery.

Also, I am pretty sure you don't need all of those `/>` slashes at the end of `<cfset>'s`.
html5 ftw.

Comment: Wheels takes what's in the sql argument and adds AS propertyName to the end. So you would end up with two ASes.